# How to convert 'iso Archive' to 'iso'? What is 'iso Archive'?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, archive, iso

I would like to request your help regarding the conversion of 'iso Achive' into 'iso'.

When I download the Xubuntu iso file from xubuntu.org, the file extension on my system (Windows 10) shows 'iso Archive'.
I cannot create a virtual machine using this 'iso Archive'.

[image]

Please advise how could I convert it to 'iso'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I have found that there was no problem with these files.

I have Docker installed on Windows 10, hence, the Hyper-V Windows feature was enabled. Once I disabled the Hyper-V feature and restarted the system, I could successfully use these files to create a virtual machine.